# Axios with TypeScript: How to tell Axios the error response shape

Tags: typescript, axios

I have an API route (using [Next.js API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction)) that has a certain response shape when successful and another when an error occurs.

```
export type ApiErrorResponse = { message: string };

export type SuccessResponse = {
  user: UserSession | null;
};

export type GetCurrentUserHandlerResponse = ApiErrorResponse | SuccessResponse;

const getCurrentUserHandler: NextApiHandler<GetCurrentUserHandlerResponse> = () => { /* ... */ };
```

How can I tell Axios what the shape of the response is depending on the error?

When I abstract away the request like this:

```
const getCurrentUserRoute = '/api/user';

const getCurrentUserRequest = () =>
  axios.get<GetCurrentUserHandlerResponse>(getCurrentUserRoute);
```

and use `getCurrentUserRequest` I always have to distinguish in both `.then` and in `.catch` whether the response is of the success shape, or of the error shape.

Ideally I'm looking for something like this:

```
const getCurrentUserRequest = () =>
  axios.get<SuccessResponse, ApiErrorResponse>(getCurrentUserRoute);
```

Ultimately I want TypeScript to be able to do this:

```
getCurrentUserRequest()
  .then((response) => {
    // now TS knows response.data is of the shape { user: UserSession | null; }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // now TS knows error.response.data is { message: string; }
  });
```

Is there a way to do that with TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be assuming a different code path for errors than the one you get with axios. More conventionally you would be implementing this in an async/await fashion and in the 'happy path' you just always assume the data is of the right shape.

```
  try {
    const response = await apiClient.get<MyObj>('/endpoint');
    const myObj: MyObj = response.data;
    return myObj;
  } catch (err) {
    // use explicit separation of error cases here
  }
```

It's only in the catch clause that you have to handle the error, and in that case you would ALWAYS have to introduce some kind of [typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) anyway to assert the proven type of the request body since there are multiple errors which could arise when making a web request.

...or is your case an Error which doesn't present as an error at the HTTP layer?